Get GDI font parameters
To create a new font by CreateFontA or CreateFontIndirectA there are many parameters needed. How to extract those parameters to make "twice larger" or "twice weight" version of existing font?
I do not see an equivalent API which will return the LOGFONTA structure of the existing font. Some parameters could be obtained via GetTextMetrics but not all.

The HFONT returned by CreateFont and CreateFontIndirect is a reference to an object that holds the original parameters specified in the call to create it.
You can get those values back out into a LOGFONT with GetObject.
// If you have an HFONT called hfont, ...
LOGFONTA lf;
if (GetObject(hfont, sizeof(lf), &lf)) {
    // The LOGFONT lf is now filled out with the same parameters
    // specified when the HFONT was created.  Many of those may
    // be 0 or default.
}

(Normally I'd use the wide (-W) versions of the APIs, but you asked specifically for the ANSI (-A) ones, so I've done that in these examples.)
The actual determination of the font you get is deferred until the font object (referenced by the HFONT) is selected into a device context.  At that point, the font mapper looks at the parameters specified and tries to find the best match from the available fonts.
So, to find the actual sizes and features of the font, you need to select the font into a device context (or an information context) and use functions to retrieve the text metrics.
// If you have an HFONT hfont and an HDC hdc, ...
HGDIOBJ hfontOriginal = SelectObject(hdc, hfont);
TEXTMETRICSA tm;
if (GetTextMetricsA(hdc, &tm)) {
    // The structure tm is now filled out with size
    // information about the selected font.  The
    // measurements are in device units.
}
char face[LF_FACESIZE] = "";
if (GetTextFaceA(hdc, ARRAYSIZE(face), face)) {
    // face is now a zero-terminated string with the
    // typeface name.  This is the version of the name
    // that you could use in a LOGFONT's lfFaceName field.
}
// If you're done with the font, make sure to put the original back.
SelectObject(hdc, hfontOriginal);

You can get additional information about the actual font selected by using the APIs to get the outline text metrics (if it's a TrueType or OpenType font).
